# how ordering makes a difference within an expression for an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an array ...

```
$a= array(1,2,3,4);
if (expr)
{ echo "if";
}
else
{ echo 'else';
}
```

When expr is  ( $a = '' || $a == 'false') , output is "if" ,

but when expr is  ( $a == 'false' || $a = '' ) , output is "else"

Can anyone explain why & how ordering makes a difference ??

Edit : I understand that I am assigning '' to $a. That is not the problem. The real question is : What does the expression `$a = ''` return? And why does reversing the order of the 2 situations switch us from the IF section to the ELSE section?

AGAIN : I UNDERSTAND I AM ASSIGNING NOT COMPARING. PLEASE ANSWER THE QUESTION AS IS.

Comment: You need to use `$a == ''` not `$a = ''` for comparison. `=` is for assignment and `== or ===` is for comparison

Comment: You are using a single = sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$a = ''` you are setting $a to an empty string. This is the same as:

```
$a = '';
if($a){
    echo 'if';
}
```

The `||` operator checks if the first condition is true and if it is, it continues with the code in the brackets. In PHP, if `$a` is set to anything, it will return `true`. In the second case `$a` does not equal the **string** `'false'` (you are not comparing it to a boolean false even!), so it executes the code in the else part.

And Fluffeh is not entirely correct. You can use the assignment operator in an if condition very effectively, you just have to be smart about it.

Comment: When will an assignment operator inside an if condition ever return false?

Comment: `if(($somevar = false) == false) echo 'false';` should print false. This can be used to shorten long if conditions. I am not advocating it, I'm just saying, that if used correctly, this is not entirely a bad practice or invalid.

Comment: Your if statement will *always* echo out the false. No matter what is in the var, false will be echoed as it is assigned - then compared. Show me a value for `$somevar` in the code above that will make that statement not echo out *false*. You have also lost whatever value was stored in `$somevar`.

Comment: Your question was _"When will an assignment operator inside an if condition ever return false?"_. I just showed you.

Comment: So, as you said, oscar, the || checks for the first expression. What happens if the first condition is false? doesn't it check for the second condition? if so, it should get false || true which should evaluate to true. Or am I getting my or condition wrong?

Answer (score 3):

First, never use `=` as a comparison operator. It is an *assignment* operator.

The difference is that `false` (as a boolean) is not the same as `'false'` as a string.

Certain expressions are type juggled by PHP to evaluate somewhat differently to how you would expect.

```
false==""
// TRUE.

false=="false"
// FALSE.
```

Additionally, when you try to compare numbers to strings, PHP will try to juggle the data so that a comparison will be performed. There is a lot to it (much more than I will post here) but you would do well to investigate type juggling and various operators. The [docs are a great start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) for this. You should also have a read of the [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) which go into a lot of detail about how various comparisons will work (depending on whether you use `==` or `===` for example).

Answer (score 0):

`$a = ''` is an assignment: you have, in error, used `=` in place of `==`. Assignment is an *expression* which has the value of the thing your assigning.

Answer (score 0):

A single equals sign `=` is the assignment opporator, so `$a = ''` is assigning an empty string to `$a` not checking if it is equal to.

In your 1st example you set the value of `$a` to an empty string, then check if it is false. An empty tring evalutes to false in php, so the conditional is true.

In your second example, you check if `$a` equals false 1st (when the value of `$a` is an array), so the conditional is false